# Power shell class method call it is own method syntax error

Tags: powershell, class, syntax-error

I have the following simple class. I'm trying to call its own method as following. But I get the syntax error.

```
# Add the necessary .NET assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http
# Create the HttpClient client
# I wanted to have it as a class member. But I get error AssemblyName not found.  
$httpClient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Httpclient;

class myClass
{
    [Byte] Hash([String]$apiKey, [String]$path)
    {
        $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512;
        $hmacsha.key = $apiKey;
        $hashed = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($path));
        return $hashed;
    }

    [Byte] Base64UrlEncode($data)
    {
        $encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($data);
        $encoded = $encoded.Split('-')[0]; 
        $encoded = $encoded.Replace('+', '-'); 
        $encoded = $encoded.Replace('*', '_'); 
        return $encoded;
    }

    setupHttpClient()
    {
        # Create the HttpClient client
        #$this.httpClient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Httpclient;
        if($global:httpClient)
        {
            # Set base address        
            $global:httpClient.BaseAddress = $this.baseAddress;
            # Hash data
            $hashed = Hash $this.apiKey $this.snapshotPath; # syntax error
            # Encode data
            $encoded = Base64UrlEncode $hashed; # syntax error
            # Setup  HttpClient client for the secure call
            $this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =  New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", $encoded);
            $this.httpClient;
        }   
    }    
  }
```

I'm new to power shell script. I'm learning by doing. That is why I might not know the correct syntax. Please let me know how can I call Hash and Base64UrlEncode  method. Currently, I get the following error. Also, how can have $httpClient as my class member:-

> Hash : The term 'Hash' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was include d, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At
>   C:\tools\backup3.ps1:20
>   char:23
>   +             $hashed = Hash $this.apiKey $this.snapshotPath;
>   +                       ~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Hash:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

After TheIncorrigible1's comment, I updated my code. Updated question about how to have httpClient as a member and return it :

```
    class DataBackup
    {

        [System.Net.Http.Httpclient]$httpClient = $null;

        DataBackup()
        {
          $this.httpClient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Httpclient;
        } 
       [System.Net.Http.Httpclient] GetHttpClient() # I got systax error here
       {
        # Create the HttpClient client
        #$this.httpClient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Httpclient;
        if($this.httpClient)
        {
            # Set base address        
            $this.httpClient.BaseAddress = $this.baseAddress;
            # Hash data
            $hashed = $this.Hash($this.apiKey, $this.snapshotPath);
            #$hashed = Hash $this.apiKey $this.snapshotPath;
            # Encode data
            $encoded = $this.Base64UrlEncode($hashed);
            # Setup  HttpClient client for the secure call
            $this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =  New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", $encoded);
            $this.httpClient;
        }   
    }
```

> At C:\tool\backup3.ps1:60 char:38
>   +         [System.Net.Http.Httpclient] GetHttpClient()
>   +                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Not all code path returns value within method.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodHasCodePathNotReturn

Comment: `$this.Hash($this.apiKey, $this.snapshotPath)`

Comment: Yes, it is working. Could you tell me how can I have $httpClient as my class member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call methods, unlike when you call functions, the arguments need to be passed in parenthesis and be the correct types.  Because your method belongs to the class, you need to utilize the `$this` automatic variable.

```
$this.Hash($this.apiKey, $this.snapshotPath)
```

versus if written as a function:

```
Get-Hash $apiKey $snapshotPath
```

The way you wrote the following, I'm not sure why you're using a class versus functions.  It's the cause of your error, however.

```
if($global:httpClient)
    {
        # Set base address        
        $global:httpClient.BaseAddress = $this.baseAddress;
        # Hash data
        $hashed = Hash $this.apiKey $this.snapshotPath; # syntax error
        # Encode data
        $encoded = Base64UrlEncode $hashed; # syntax error
        # Setup  HttpClient client for the secure call
        $this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =  New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", $encoded);
        $this.httpClient;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is working. Could you tell me how can I have $httpClient as my class member?

Comment: @masiboo Just declare the variable outside of the methods.

Comment: "When you call methods, unlike when you call functions, the arguments need to be passed in parenthesis and be the correct types." - Do You know any documentation URL for this statement?

Comment: @Nashev [This is the full documentation for PowerShell functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6).  [Here's documentation on methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_methods?view=powershell-6).